# How to show the elements ${x^p}$ and $y$ are commute based on relation ${x^y}={x^{1+p}}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

This is a follow up to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3678711/10513) question.

Let $G = \langle x,y,z\mid{x^{{p^2}}} = {y^p} = {z^p} = 1,{x^y} = {x^{1+p}},[x,z] = [y,z] = 1\rangle$.

How to show ${x^p}$ and $y$ are commute based on relation ${x^y}={x^{1+p}}$?

I have tried to solve it but i'm stuck. Please help me.

if ${x^y}=x.{x^p}$, then
${y^{-1}}xy=x.{x^p}$. from this i got $xy=yx.{x^p}$.

we have $x^y = x^{1+p}$

let $(x^p)^y = x^{1+p}$,
     $(x^y)^p = ({x^{1+p})^p}= x^p.x^{p^2}$

let $x^p$ be the element in $G$,

$(x^p)y = y(x^p).x^{p^2}=y(x^p)$ since $x^{p^2}=1$.

is it true?

Comment: You should link back to your previous question, as this was essentially (briefly) answered in the comments there.

Comment: @user1729 okay, thank you. i just want to confirm the answer.

Comment: No problem. Its just nice to see how everything is related, so we can follow chains in the future (e.g. if someone read your first question, then then can come here for the next bit). I've added a link to your original question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is correct, although I'd say it is a little more lengthy than necessary. I'd summarize it as
$$
y^{-1}x^p y = (y^{-1}x y)^p = (x^{1 + p})^p = x^p x^{p^2} = x^p.
$$
Multiplying this equation by $y$ from the left, we get $x^p y = y x^p$.

Comment: thank you for the respond.