# How to find the number of elements of order $p$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation, p-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

This is a follow up to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3680226/how-to-show-the-elements-xp-and-y-are-commute-based-on-relation-xy-x?noredirect=1#comment7562840_3680226) question.

Let $G = \langle x,y,z\mid{x^{{p^2}}} = {y^p} = {z^p} = 1,{x^y} = {x^{1+p}},[x,z] = [y,z] = 1\rangle$.

By euler phi function, the number of elements of order $p$ is $p-1$.

For each generator, the number of elements of order $p$ is in the following.
generator $x$ = $p-1$.
generator $y$ = $p-1$.
generator $z$ = $p-1$.
There are $3(p-1)$ elements of order $p$ from the generators.

But, how to find the rest of the elements of order $p$? Is it there are more simple way to find the number of elements of order $p$ in a finite group?

I hope someone can give me some idea regarding this question? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$First of all, note that $G$ is an (internal) direct product
$$
G = \Span{x, y} \times \Span{z}.
$$
Since $\Span{z}$ is cyclic of order $p$, you have only to find the number $N$ of elements of order *dividing* $p$ in $H = \Span{x, y}$. Then the total number of elements of order $p$ of $G$ will be $N p - 1$.

Now $N$ is different for $p = 2$ and for $p$ odd.

For $p = 2$, the group $H$ is dihedral of order $8$, and so you should know that it has $5$ elements of order $2$, so $N = 6$ here.

For $p > 2$, a direct computation yields
$$
\tag{power}
(x^{i} y^{j})^{p}
=
x^{i p} y^{j p}
=
x^{i p},
$$
so that $x^{i} y^{j}$ has order dividing $p$ iff $p$ divides $i$. Thus $N = p^{2}$ here.

You get (power) from the standard identity, valid in a group where commutators are central
$$
(a b)^{n} = a^{n} b^{n} [b, a]^{\binom{n}{2}}.
$$

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer. But, i'm still not clear how to get $N={p^2}$. If you don't mind, can you explain more details? And what kind of books or papers that you have referred. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @Alia, $x^{i} y^{j}$ has order dividing $p$ fro arbitrary $j$ (for which you have $p$ choices) and $i$ a multiple of $p$ (for which you have $p$ choices), hence $N = p^{2}$. Any basic text in group theory wil have the identity I used.

Comment: i see. thank you for the explanation!

Comment: sorry, i have one more question regarding this proof. how can you be sure that the product of two elements of order p must give an element of order p? Thank you.

Comment: In general it is not true. But if $G = H \times K$, and $h \in H, k \in K$, then $(h k)^{p} = h^{p} k^{p} = 1$ iff $h^{p} = 1 = k^{p}$.

Comment: now it is clear. thank you for the answer!

Comment: sorry, again. i'm really appreciate it if you can give me the reference for the above statement. I've tried to search but i didn't find it. I need that to put in my thesis. Thank you.