# How to prove the number of the elements of order $p$ in a group of order $p^4$ is ${p^3}-1$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation, p-groups

This is a follow up to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3709658/how-to-find-the-number-of-elements-of-order-p/3709747?noredirect=1#comment7629775_3709747) question.

Let $G = \langle x,y,z\mid{x^p} = {y^p} = {z^{p^2}} = 1,[x,y] = z,[x,z] = [y,z] = 1\rangle$.

To find the number of elements of order $p$, can i use the same approach as question before? By using the commutator identities?
$$(ab)^n = a^nb^n[b,a]^{\binom{n}{2}}$$

I'm a little bit confuse since in this case ${z^{p^2}}=1$ not ${x^{p^2}}=1$.

Comment: For each $j$, $(xy^j)^p$ will be a power of $z$. I'd start by determining **which** power.

Comment: i'm sorry but i didnt clear with the statement. do you means that $z^{(x{y^j})^p}$?

Comment: I'm sure I meant what I wrote.

Comment: ok, then. i'll try to prove. thank you

Comment: Although the group presentation tells you that $z$ has order dividing $p^2$, in fact it has order dividing $p$. Because $1=[x^p,y]= [x,y]^p = z^p$ (with the middle equality because you have a nilpotent group of class $2$).

Comment: I don't understand why the now-deleted first answer got a downvote and a vote for deletion. It looks correct to me, and, although terse, agrees with Arturo's answer.

Comment: @user1729: I agree; if that poster will undelete, I will certainly upvote.

Comment: sorry. i'm a newbie here. i dont know how the first answer is deleted. i'm not deleted the first answer although i'm still not clear with it due to my lack of knowledge.

Comment: @Alia: You did not delete the first answer; the author did, after he got an unwarranted downvote and someone voted to delete the answer. As to accepting answers, once your question has been answered to your satisfaction, you click on the check mark on the left of the answer that you feel has been most useful to you. Once you get enough reputation, you will also be able to up-vote answers that you find useful (for both your questions and other people’s questions).n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This group does not have order $p^4$; it has order $p^3$ and is the Heisenberg group. I’m assuming $p$ is odd.

To verify that $z$ in fact has order (dividing) $p$, note because $z$ is central, the group is nilpotent of class (at most) $2$, and so the commutator bracket is bilinear. From this, you have that
$$z^p = [x,y]^p = [x^p,y] = [1,y] = 1.$$
So even though the presentation tells you that the order of $z$ divides $p^2$, in fact it divides $p$.

It is clear that this group has the Heisenberg group as a quotient (mod out by $z^p$). But since $z^p$ is trivial, the group has order at most $p^3$ (every element can be written, by collection, as $x^ay^bz^c$, with $0\leq a,b,c\lt p$), and since it has the Heisenberg group as a quotient, it has order *exactly* $p^3$ and is isomorphic to the Heisenberg group.

The number of elements of order $p$ in this group is $p^3-1$.

Now, you could have a group of order $p^4$ with generators of the given order if you had the group
$$G = \langle x,y,z\mid x^p=y^p=z^{p^2}=[x,z]=[y,z]=1, [x,y]=z^p\rangle$$
(that is $z$, is a $p$th root of the commutator $[x,y]$, instead of being equal to the commutator). That is a group obtained by adding a central $p$th root to the commutator in the Heisenberg group. Could that be the group you were supposed to look at?

In that case, we have that elements are of the form $x^ay^bz^c$ with $0\leq a,b\lt p$, $0\leq c\lt p^2$. Then you would have
$$\begin{align*}
(x^ay^bz^c)^n &= (x^ay^b)^nz^{nc}\\
&= x^{an}y^{bn}[y^b,x^a]^{\binom{n}{2}}z^{nc}\\
&= x^{an}y^{bn}[y,x]^{ab\binom{n}{2}}z^{nc}.
\end{align*}$$
If $n=p$ and $p$ is odd, then $x^{ap}=y^{bp}=[y,x]^{ab\binom{p}{2}}=1$ (since $\binom{p}{2}$ is a multiple of $p$). Thus, $x^ay^bz^c$ has order dividing $p$ if and only if $z^{pc}=1$, if and only if $p|c$. Thus, the elements of order dividing $p$ are of the form $x^ay^bz^{kp}$, with $0,\leq a,b,k\lt p$. This gives you $p^3$ elements. But if $a=b=k=0$ you get the identity, so this leads to exactly $p^3-1$ elements of order $p$.

Answer (score 2):

The group is nilpotent of class 2 so the commutator is linear in both arguments. In particular $[x,y]^p=[x^p, y]=1=z^p$. Since every element is uniqely represented as $x^ky^mz^n$,  $0\le k,m,n\le p-1$, the number of elements of your group is $p^3$ and all nontrivial elements have order $p$. This is the Heisenberg group of order $p^3$.

Comment: sorry if i'm wrong. but this is the group presentation of 3-generator groups of order ${p^4}$. Suppose the number of elements of this group is ${p^4}$, right? And for this case ${z^{p^2}}=1$.

Comment: You are wrong. I proved that the order is $p^3$.

Comment: oh ya? how is it? if you don't mind, can you explain the proof to me?

Comment: It's not the Heisenberg group. Where do you get $z^p=1$?

Comment: the proof is in my answer.

Comment: yes, i dont think this a heisenberg group. the group presentation is straightly shows that ${z^{p^2}}$ and this group presentation is taken from burnside and revised by Kim Ok in his paper.

Comment: ok. i'll check again later from the books. btw, thank you for the answer and explanation!

Comment: Wikipedia says that Kim Ok was the fourth wife of Kim Jong-il. Her achivements in math are not known. Incidentally there is a Wikipeda article on Commutator. Identity 3 there is what you need.

Comment: @user158834  Your answer should never have been downvoted, nor should it have received a delete vote.  It is a correct answer.  But please understand that there are many users on this site with the capacity to answer this question, and that accusing anyone who answers the same question you answered of plagiarism is a *very serious accusation*, and cannot be substantiated.  I am sorry that users with over 300K in rep automatically get a pass, no matter what they answer, while users without so much rep are wrongly criticized.  But I truly believe there was no ill intent here.